# how to apply intervention analysis to time series ARIMA?

Tags: r, time-series, outliers

I have weekly sales data for a restaurant, with 113 observations, and every year in January, sales drop significantly and then recover after two or four weeks. I applied a SARIMA model with auto-arima in R, but when I evaluate my model, I realize that the residuals are not constant and not normally distributed. Box-Cox Transformation was already used, lamba was 1.99 but it did not improve the model.

Upon reviewing a time series text, I learned that I need to create a dummy variable. I looked at the observations where the pattern breaks in January and classified them as "1", with the others as zero. I estimated my model again and it resulted in a SARIMA with rgex, but when I reviewed the residuals, I still have extremely high residuals in those periods. Residuals used to be -10000, now they are mostly -5000, so they were reduced. Do you have any suggestions? What types of interventions exist? I placed "1" for the first few weeks of January, then "0" when I see that sales have reached their normal level. To test for stationarity, I used the Augmented Dickey-Fuller test and found that the data was not stationary. Therefore, I differenced the time series and checked for stationarity again using the ADF test. Next, I decomposed the time series into its seasonal, trend, and residual components and plotted the results. I then fit a SARIMA model using auto.arima and checked its diagnostic tests for accuracy. Additionally, I performed a Box-Ljung test to check for autocorrelation in the residuals and a Jarque-Bera test for normality. Box-Ljung was fine, but Jarque-Bera was not. I then added a dummy variable for intervention analysis to account for outliers or extreme values in the data. I fit a second SARIMA model using the dummy variable and checked its diagnostic tests for accuracy. However, yI found that the variance was still high, and upon further investigation, I found that the highest residuals corresponded to the same period that I alreadt included in the dummy variable for intervention. What else could I do? any suggestion? thanks!

Comment: Since you already have taken maulti steps to improve your models, explore other variables that may be influencing your sales during the period of interest. For example, there may be changes in weather patterns, holidays, or events in the area that could affect your restaurant sales. You might want to try to include these variables as exogenous variables in your SARIMA models.